# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, windows-server-2012-r2

TLDR: Does anyone know what C++ Redist version and/or VSTA package I need that provides Applications.Core Version 10..? Assuming that is the actual issue.

---

We have an SSIS package running on Windows 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008. VS C++ Redist 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed... as well as  VSTA 2.0 ENU.

Migrating everything to a new server, Windows 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2014.
I've installed VS C++ Redist 2013, 2015... as well as VSTA 2015.

When the SSIS package is run from the new server, it almost immediately throws the following exception.

> There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Now I'm sure I could go and install every old C++ Redist out there, and the old VSTA versions as well, then once it starts working uninstall all the others.  But I would prefer **not** to make a mess on this server by installing and uninstalling tons of unnecessary stuff... leaving behind bits and pieces of software.

In the Job Step Properties => General (tab) => Execution Options (tab). . . . there is a "Use 32 bit runtime" option that is not checked.  Checking it and re-running my process has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help, did you try it?

http://pietervanhove.azurewebsites.net/?p=461

EDIT - from the link above:
To overcome the issue just install the Installation of SQL Server Data Tools and Integration Services at the same time.
The SQL Server Installation Wizard detects that it still has to install the Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 3.0
Both x64 and x86 Tools are installed than.

[image]

Comment: This looks promising... I'll get with our server admin tomorrow and try it, then report back. Thanks!

Comment: MS bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776248/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-tools-applications-core

Answer (score 1):

I found Easy Solution as below,
Go to Solution Explorer --> *Right Click* **Solution -->Property**

Change **Run64BitRunTime=False**

It works for me.

[Click for image of Solution Explorer-->Change to 32Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBVSg.jpg)

Comment: Old post, but this solution worked for me as well. My case: I needed to resurrect a VS 2010 package, and had a breakpoint set in code. Upon running, I got the error mentioned above. Setting 64Bit in the project properties did the trick (Chandramohan mentions in the solution, but I think it's actually in the project properties).